# Is it possible to push all existing lines of a text file down and write something on first line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, insert, text-files, prepend

As the title suggests, if I have an existing text file with the following content:

```
Hello
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
```

Is it possible in any way to push everything down a line and write new text to the first line so it looks like this?

```
Stuff I Added
Hello
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

No common modern-day OS has a file model that supports prepending or inserting in the middle. You need to make a new file, write your new first line to it, copy all of the lines from the original file to the new file, then replace the old file with the new one.

Comment: Fair enough, seems simple to implement. Just thought it would be easier.

Comment: you don't have to create a new file -- you can read the contents of the original, move the pointer back to the start, and save the new data (or close it in read mode and reopen it in write mode)

Comment: @BryanOakley true. Either is valid, depending on whether you want to temporarily have two copies of the content on disk, or temporarily have the entire content in RAM.